# Why when I extract from my database it automatically adds new lines?

Tags: sql, csv

For example, my database would have an entry that says "This is a title". In server management studio, it would present it as that one line. Whenever I try to export or copy and paste that result into excel, it turns into

```
This
Is
A 
Title
```

in 4 different cells

Instead of

```
This is a title
```

in one cell

Why is this happening and do I fix it so I can just have the data in one cell when I export?

Comment: In Excel type something into a cell, click "Text to Columns" on the "Data" tab, set it to fixed-width or change the delimiter options so that space isn't a delimiter.  Excel will remember the last setting you had and will use this when you paste in new data.  It might not be this but it fits the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Does it do this when you paste into Excel only, or would it also go to four lines when you paste into something like Notepad?

Comment: It would look fine in Notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting to the database using python and examining the data in text, it seems as though the data had the new line escape character,`\n`,'embedded in them. This is what resulted in excel displaying them as new lines.